# Fastboot recognizes device but unable to flash (stuck with no output)

Tags: adb, custom-roms, fastboot, linux

I'm trying to flash a custom ROM on my Android smartphone using `fastboot`. When trying to flash the recovery, the command does not output anything and is stuck.

```
./fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
```

### Environment:

- ROM: [PixelExperience 11 (Plus) (Official for X00TD)](https://wiki.pixelexperience.org/devices/X00TD/install/)
- Recovery: Supplied with the ROM
- Smartphone: Asus Zenfone Max Pro M1 (X00TD / ZB601KL Variant)
- PC:

```
                 /////////////                user@pop-os 
             /////////////////////            ------------- 
          ///////*767////////////////         OS: Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS x86_64 
        //////7676767676*//////////////       Host: 80F6 Lenovo B40-80 
       /////76767//7676767//////////////      Kernel: 5.15.8-76051508-generic 
      /////767676///*76767///////////////     Uptime: 54 mins 
     ///////767676///76767.///7676*///////    Packages: 1896 (dpkg), 27 (flatpak) 
    /////////767676//76767///767676////////   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
    //////////76767676767////76767/////////   Resolution: 1366x768 
    ///////////76767676//////7676//////////   DE: GNOME 
    ////////////,7676,///////767///////////   WM: Mutter 
    /////////////*7676///////76////////////   WM Theme: Pop 
    ///////////////7676////////////////////   Theme: Pop-dark [GTK2/3] 
     ///////////////7676///767////////////    Icons: Pop [GTK2/3] 
      //////////////////////'////////////     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
       //////.7676767676767676767,//////      CPU: Intel i5-5200U (4) @ 2.700GHz 
        /////767676767676767676767/////       GPU: Intel HD Graphics 5500 
          ///////////////////////////         Memory: 2679MiB / 7865MiB 
             /////////////////////
                 /////////////
```

(Also tried, unsuccessfully in the older **Kubuntu 18.04**, with the same result)

I've tried using both the system supplied (Ubuntu repository) version of `fastboot` and the one shipped with [Android's platform tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools).
Installed the system version with `sudo apt install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot`.

### `fastboot` Versions:

```
user@pop-os:~$ fastboot --version
fastboot version 1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/fastboot
```

```
user@pop-os:~/Android/platform-tools$ ./fastboot --version
fastboot version 31.0.3-7562133
Installed as /home/user/Android/platform-tools/fastboot
```

### Prerequisites:

Have configured `udev` rules as shown below (to avoid "no permission" error when running fastboot without sudo)

```
#/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

And added current user to the 'plugdev' group with `sudo usermod -aG plugdev $LOGNAME`

### Issue:

After rebooting into fastboot mode through either the hardware keys (VOLUME UP + POWER) or the command `./adb reboot bootloader`, my device is recognized by fastboot.

```
user@pop-os:~/Android/platform-tools$ ./fastboot devices
XXXXXXXX04HP    fastboot
```

**But when I try to flash the recovery, the command gives no output and is stuck**

```
user@pop-os:~/Android/platform-tools$ ./fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
```

And just when I unplug the device from the PC, it gives an error

```
user@pop-os:~/Android/platform-tools$ ./fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
Sending 'recovery' (21517 KB)                      FAILED (Write to device failed (No such device))
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

### Conclusion:

As recommended in the hyperlinked guide and other resources, I have tried using different USB ports (both 2.0 & 3.0), different cables and, as mentioned, different PC and version of Ubuntu. Nothing resolved the issue.

**However, using Windows 10 with the same PC (its dual-booted), USB port, cable and the mobile device, I was able to successfully flash the recovery and later the ROM also.**

There are similar questions to this one with some whose accepted answers are not very helpful and most of them are old. I would really like some help with this issue.

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: as you already pointed out it's not an issue with the android phone but with linux, i suggest to migrate that question to https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Posted it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/684494/508210). Thanks @alecxs